# Searching a static array on Multiple Indexes C#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, dictionary, collections

This is a question probably not just of what collection to use, but what methods are best to use to access the data once it is defined. I am a relative newbie to C# and .NET, but I have been through a couple simple projects and need some direction on doing searches on smaller sets of static data. Specifically I have a class defined similar to this:

```
public class rlsSoftwareVersions
{
    public double   dReleaseNum { get; set; }
    public string   strReleaseName { get; set; }
    public long     lConfigSchema { get; set; }
    public long     lProgramSchema { get; set; }
}
```

We have a straightforward array of those class objects defined as follows:

```
static rlsSoftwareVersions[] rlsSoftware = {   
    new rlsSoftwareVersions { dReleaseNum = 4.0, strReleaseName = "Chronos", lConfigSchema = 0x04, lProgramSchema = 0x0DB4 },
    new rlsSoftwareVersions { dReleaseNum = 4.1, strReleaseName = "Hera",   lConfigSchema = 0x06, lProgramSchema = 0x0DB5 },
    new rlsSoftwareVersions { dReleaseNum = 5.0, strReleaseName = "Zeus",   lConfigSchema = 0x0C, lProgramSchema = 0x0DB5 },
    new rlsSoftwareVersions { dReleaseNum = 5.1, strReleaseName = "Poseidon",lConfigSchema = 0x0C, lProgramSchema = 0x0DBB }
    .. .. .. .. 
    .. .. .. .. 
    .. .. .. .. 
};
```

That array extends for about 30 more entries.  My question is this. I have been going through learning about using Dictionaries for doing searches by index. But that seems to allow searching on one index only. What I need is to be able to access this kind of data (in the array) by searching based on any of the properties and getting a returned collection of the values in the other member properties of matching objects.

For example, in one case, I want to get the collection of values for lConfigSchema that return when I match the dReleaseNum property to 4.0.  Then, the next time I want the collection of values for dReleaseNum, then the lConfigSchema property is equal to 0x0C.  I want to basically do this kind of look up on any property and get the results (Collection) of any other associated property.

I am just finishing up looking through dictionaries, but they appear to only work with a single index.  I am either looking at this wrong or looking at using the wrong kind of class to do this. Any direction suggestions you can push me towards? It feels like I am trying to use a hammer when I should be using a knife..

Caveat: I can't create a DB for this. It needs to all be in a single resultant executable without external database or files. Which is why I created the internal static array...

Thanks

Comment: Could you store things in a database table and then use LINQ to access each column?  -- Just a thought

Comment: First thing first! stop using Hungarian notation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using LINQ?

```
IEnumerable<rlsSoftwareVersions> result = rlsSoftwareVersions.Where(item => item.dReleaseNumber == 4.0);

foreach(var rlsSoftwareVersion in result)
{
    // do something
}
```

here are some useful examples: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Thank you!  both for the sample code you provide for my current issue and for the LINQ link...